# How do I load a CSV file into a LiveCode stack?

Tags: csv, livecode

Assuming I have a background with fieldA, fieldB and fieldC I would like to load a CSV file into a stack. The CSV file has three columns A, B and C. How does the script of the 'Load' button look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to load the contents verbatim, then

```
on mouseUp
  put url ("file:" & pathToFile) into tContents
end mouseUp
```

will do the trick.
To get the columns into the fields you have to do a bit more work. One way:

```
on mouseUp
  put url ("file:" & pathToFile) into tContents
  -- set the itemDelimiter to tab -- if necessary
  repeat for each line tLine in tContents
    put item 1 of tLine & cr after field "fieldA"
    put item 2 of tLine & cr after field "fieldB"
    put item 3 of tLine & cr after field "fieldC"
  end repeat
end mouseUp
```

Comment: Where is the call to `create card`?

Comment: I guess you would put that in the repeat loop if you must use a card based database... if the CSV file is created in a spreadsheet it probably has quotes around some or all fields. There's some libraries around for parsing CSV.. probably on rev online...

Answer (score 0):

If the data is clean a CSV files normally has the field separated by ";" so you can just replace them with tab and use an "basic table field":

```
put url ("file:" & pathToFile) into tData
replace ";" with tab in tData
put tData into field "data"
```

If your data is UTF8 or something else you need to translate it first.

Comment: **clean a CSV files** should of course be __a clean CSV file it__

Comment: Works for ANSI data, but not for UFT-8. I use `put uniencode(tData, "utf8") into tData`. How do I set the unicodeText of the table field?
`put tData into the unicodeText of field "data"` gives a syntax error. Field "data" is the grid.

Comment: You need to do `set the unicodeText of field "data" to tData`

Comment: CSV means 'comma separated values'. So the field delimiter is a comma, though when saving the file e.g. in LibreOffice calc you may choose the field delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

To read the data into variable lCsvData:

```
local lCsvData

on importCsv
  answer file "Chooose CSV file..."
  if it is not empty then
    put it into myPath
    put url ("binfile:" & myPath) into myData
```

Now we can decode the data:

```
    put urlDecode(urlEncode(myData,"UTF8")) into myData
```

Problem: data can contain returns. Lets remove the returns from the items. If necessary, you can process each item separately.

```
    put empty into lCsvData
    set the itemDel to semicolon
    repeat for each line myLine in myData
      repeat for each item myItem in myLine
        put replaceText(myItem,cr,numToChar(14)) after lCsvData
      end repeat
      put cr after lCsvData
    end repeat
  end if
end importCsv
```

Now you have clean data. You can choose a line and put it into a field this way:

```
on showLine theLine
  put line theLine of of lCsvData into myLine
  set the itemDel to semicolon
  repeat for each item myItem in myLine
    put replaceText(myLine,numToChar(14),tab) into fld 1
  end repeat
end showLine
```

where theLine is an integer. You can use cr instead of tab and you could adjust this script in any way you want to format the output field.